The kernel of the augmentation map is finitely generated
Suppose $M$ is a monoid and consider the ring monoid $A = \mathbb{Z} \cdot M$. We say that $M$ is bi-FP1 if there exists a resolution:
$$F_1 \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$$
of $A$ in the category of finitely generated free $A$-bimodules. What I want to prove is that if $M$ is bi-FP1 then the kernel of the map $\phi : A \otimes A \mapsto A$ given by $\phi (x \otimes y ) = xy $ is the $A$-bimodule generated by $\{ 1 \otimes a - a\otimes 1 | a \in \Sigma \}$ (which I did) and that it is finitely generated (which I did not). I tried a categorical approach using the fact that a free module has the projective property but it didn't get me anywhere. Any ideas?
